# Error Validation in wrong language first time

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, JSF 2.x, JPA 2 with Hibernate Provider. The application run on Tomcat 6.X.

The web-app can be show in different languages : en , es , fr.

I use the bean validation

```
@Size(max=20)
@NotBlank
```

I don't understand why but every time I validate a form with an error to test the bean validation. The message display in english, but when i resubmit its display in the good lang.

In my page i set the lang like this:

```
<f:view locale="#{localeBackManager.currentLocale}" contentType="text/html">
```

My bundle display in the good lang. I have the same problem with the `required` messages.

What should I do to have the error message in same lang as the navigation lang at the first time ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the locale in the view was not sufficient:

```
<f:view locale="#{localeBackManager.currentLocale}" contentType="text/html">
```

You should set the locale in the code like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
```